# Two supposedly compatible function pointer types is being warned as incompatible. What rule am I breaking?

Tags: c, types, warnings

I have a set of functions for performing unsigned modular multiplication over large integers. For some reason, when I use my generic remainder function in the multiplication, the compiler (I'm using Clang with `-Wall -Wextra` warning flags) gives incompatible pointer warning.

Header:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t v[];
} vlong_t; // generic incomplete type.

vlong_t *vlong_remv_inplace(vlong_t *rem, const vlong_t *b);

typedef void *(*vlong_modfunc_t)(
    vlong_t *restrict v,
    void *restrict ctx);

vlong_t *vlong_mulv(
    vlong_t *restrict out,
    const vlong_t *a,
    const vlong_t *b,
    vlong_modfunc_t modfunc,
    void *restrict mod_ctx);
```

Test code section that's giving the warning:

```c
vlong_mulv(x, a, b, vlong_remv_inplace, b);
```

I've simplified the code a bit to create a minimal working example, my coding style have different variable naming conventions among others.

The warning is as follow:

```
vlong-test.c:85:20: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'vlong_t *(vlong_t *, const vlong_t *)' to parameter of type 'vlong_modfunc_t'
      (aka 'void *(*)(vlong_t *restrict, void *restrict)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

vlong_mulv(x, a, b, vlong_remv_inplace, b);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What rule am I breaking here?

Comment: Different return type, different argument types

Comment: My thoughts were that using `void *` could make "composite type" compatibility possible. I'll examine the draft standard a bit more for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vlong_t *vlong_remv_inplace(vlong_t *rem, const vlong_t *b);

typedef void *(*vlong_modfunc_t)(
    vlong_t *restrict v,
    void *restrict ctx);

vlong_t *vlong_mulv(
    vlong_t *restrict out,
    const vlong_t *a,
    const vlong_t *b,
    vlong_modfunc_t modfunc,
    void *restrict mod_ctx);
```

the function `vlong_remv_implace` takes a pointer to `vlong_t`, and a pointer to `const vlong_t`, while the `vlong_modfunc_t` type describes a pointer to a function that takes a restricted pointer to `vlong_t` and a restricted pointer to a non-`const` `vlong_t`.  The `const`ness should match (and probably also the `restrict`ness of the pointer parameters, which is also different) for the pointer types to match.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is right, I'm using different return and argument types.

While most C calling conventions following `ILP32`, `LP64`, or `IL32LLP64` mandate all pointers be passed just like `size_t` to callees, the standard doesn't preclude possible "lunati-c" implementation from passing pointers to different types to possibly different sets of registers. And that is irrespective of the fact that all object pointers can be casted to `void *` and back losslessly.

The C standard working draft (n2573) has this to say:

6.3.2.3. §8

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: That paragraph is not talking about the parameter types of the function related to the subject pointer (which is the pointer to a function)  In this case a function pointer type to a function that takes one `void *` parameter and another function pointer type to a function that takes a different  pointer parameter doesn't make the function pointer types compatible... they are indeed incompatibles.  E.g. `void (*A)(void *)` and `void (*B)(char *)` are not compatible pointers to function types, despite the fact that you can pass a `void *` to `*B` or a `char *` to `*A` in the call.

Answer (score 0):

The function *vlong_remv_inplace* must have the same signature as the type *vlong_modfunc_t* so in *vlong_remv_inplace* you need to replace the type of the second parameter and the result with a void pointer:

```
void *vlong_remv_inplace(vlong_t *rem, void *b);
```

The alternative is to change the signature of the type *vlong_modfunc_t* to match the signature of the function *vlong_remv_inplace*.